# Bootstrap: How to position Image in Centre absolute?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I place image in centre of page, behind the `<div>` in responsive html.

I am using `IMG` with position `absolute`
and `DIV` - position `relative`

so IMG is behind this is what i wanted but when i resize screen IMG get wrong positions always any fix for this ?

HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center center-block">
            <img src="../res/uvod-ahoj.png" class="" alt="" id="uvod-ahoj">
            <div id="uvod-ahoj-div">
                <h1>Ahoj, som...</h1>
                <p>
                    <strong>Marcela Špalková</strong> a s pekným oblečením sa kamarátim od malička. Začalo to listovaním módnych
                    časopisov, pokračovalo vymýšľaním vlastných outfitov a šitím šiat pre bábiky. Táto moja vášen
                    sa naplno prejavila pri nákupoch, vyberala som kúsky nielen pre seba, ale aj pre kamarátky.
                </p>
                <a href="" class="btn" id="uvod-btn">POZRIEŤ MOJE SLUŽBY</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS :

```
#uvod-ahoj {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: 14%;
}
#uvod-ahoj-div {
position: relative;
color: white;
background-color: #780d4f;
}
#uvod-ahoj-div > h1 {
color: white;
margin: 3rem 0;
padding: 3rem 0 0 0;
}
#uvod-ahoj-div > p {
margin: auto;
max-width: 60rem;
padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used `left:50%` with `transform` property in `#uvod-ahoj`

```css
#uvod-ahoj {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
}
#uvod-ahoj-div {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: #780d4f;
}
#uvod-ahoj-div > h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  padding: 3rem 0 0 0;
}
#uvod-ahoj-div > p {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 60rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 text-center center-block">
    <img src="../res/uvod-ahoj.png" class="" alt="" id="uvod-ahoj">
    <div id="uvod-ahoj-div">
        <h1>Ahoj, som...</h1>
        <p>
            <strong>Marcela Špalková</strong> a s pekným oblečením sa kamarátim od malička. Začalo to listovaním módnych
            časopisov, pokračovalo vymýšľaním vlastných outfitov a šitím šiat pre bábiky. Táto moja vášen
            sa naplno prejavila pri nákupoch, vyberala som kúsky nielen pre seba, ale aj pre kamarátky.
        </p>
        <a href="" class="btn" id="uvod-btn">POZRIEŤ MOJE SLUŽBY</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

since the image is inside the Div tag,
you can set a class name for Img tag.and then set **padding-left:50%;**